# What is the best way to play MMS/RTSP streams in C#?

Tags: c#, audio-streaming, mms, rtsp

Is there something like libmms, librtsp or xine-lib for C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the [BASS library](http://www.un4seen.com) successfully for these types of streams. 
It should be able to do it with the WMA plugin.

It's written in C/C++ , but there is a .NET wrapper available.

It also supports mp3 and ogg/aac (with plugins)

You may also try to host the Media Player, if the target is Windows Forms/WPF.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a free solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: BASS / BASS.Net is free for non-commercial usage.